# Wpf Media element Black screen Error after long time

Tags: wpf, video, memory, screen, mediaelement

I am using a MediaElement

```
MediaVideo.Width = this.Width;
MediaVideo.Height = this.Height;
MediaVideo.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
MediaVideo.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
MediaVideo.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Stop;
MediaVideo.Source = new Uri(infoZone.MediaFileName);
MediaVideo.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
MediaVideo.MediaEnded += media_MediaEnded;
MediaVideo.Play();
```

when it is finished i clear it:

```
MediaVideo.Stop();
MediaVideo.Source = null;
```

I am calling this function again and again, i have no memory problems, but afer few hours and sometimes, few days, the mediaElement is correctly loaded but it only display a black screen and pass to the next mediaElement.

I also think than the "MediaEnded" event is not correctly call after a long time, so i also tryed with a timer set with the video duration.

If somebody have a solution, thanks a lot

Comment: did you tried adding mediaFailed event and see what errors it throws.

Comment: nop but i could, i do it and if i have an error i will post it here
thx

Comment: any solution on this ?

Comment: Hi Banng, after few month of research, it's seems than the Wpf mediaElement have memory leaks. So if you need a solution like that, it is better to use a Winform component